# Is it possible that a single class extends a whole package?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package

So it would be:

```
void myClass(Class<? extends src.auxiliar.*> object) {
   //TODO
}
```

Where all the classes in `auxiliar` are subclasses of `Object`.

Yes, it would be easier to simply put :

```
void myClass(Class<? extends Object> object) {
   //TODO
}
```

And even easier:

```
void myClass(Object object) {
   //TODO
}
```

But for my original purpose, in case this is possible, it would make it fairly easier.

Comment: This is not really a question.

Comment: Your question shows a wrong understanding of [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). The one inside the angle brackets (`<...>`) does not declare/restrict the type of the class itself, but the type of the type parameter. For example, for a list, it declare/restricts the type of the elements that can be contained in that list. What you ask is not possible because the type must be known at compile time but a class can be added to a package at runtime (to name a single reason only).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't `extends` a whole package instead of that you can create an `interface` and `implements` all class in package to that `interface`.